# linear-gradient in different browsers

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have written a CSS style using linear-gradient to give a rectangle a wire-frame effect like so:

```
background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent calc(50% - 1px), #000 calc(50% - 1px), #000 50%, transparent 50%),
  linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent calc(50% - 1px), #000 calc(50% - 1px), #000 50%, transparent 50%),
  linear-gradient(to left, transparent calc(100% - 1px), #000 calc(100% - 1px), #000 100%, transparent 100%),
  linear-gradient(to right, transparent calc(100% - 1px), #000 calc(100% - 1px), #000 100%, transparent 100%),
  linear-gradient(to top, transparent calc(100% - 1px), #000 calc(100% - 1px), #000 100%, transparent 100%),
  linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent calc(100% - 1px), #000 calc(100% - 1px), #000 100%, transparent 100%) #ccc!important;
```

The issue I am having is that the style appears as I want on Firefox but not so much on Chrome.

Is there a way I can alter my code so I can make the wire-frame look the same on Chrome?

I am using the latest version of Firefox and Chrome on a Mac.

I have attached screenshots to describe what I am currently seeing.

**Firefox**
[image: firefox]
**Chrome**
[image: chrome]

Comment: i'll update my question to say i am using a mac

Comment: Can you please describe what you're seeing and what you're hoping for? Although my guess is that it doesn't like the `calc`s, have you considered using `49%` and `51%` to get a thin line?